# context.frame_set() not updating every time

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am trying to build a tool for calculating the IK pole angle of a constraint, I already posted a question here, but no answers.
So I decided to go for brute force. Running a for loop and trying angles between -180 and 180 and seeing the difference with the rest position of the bone.

But the script does't works i returns too many angles supposed to be the right one when the truth is that only have one exact angle.

Here is the evaluating function, the full operator is a bit longer, so I put on [PasteAll](http://pasteall.org/552635/python)

```
# context is the bpy.context,
# p_bone is the pose bone with the constraint
# ik is the Inverse kinimatics constraint on the p_bone
# angle is the angle to try and score
def ik_test(context, p_bone, ik, angle):
    # mute constraint for getting original vectors of the bone
    ik.mute = True
    # then update the scene
    context.scene.frame_set(context.scene.frame_current)
    # get some vecotrs
    v1 = p_bone.vector
    x1 = p_bone.x_axis
    z1 = p_bone.z_axis

    # unmute the constraint
    ik.mute = False
    # set the pole_angle for the test
    ik.pole_angle = angle
    # update the scene again
    context.scene.frame_set(context.scene.frame_current)
    # get the new vectors
    v2 = p_bone.vector
    x2 = p_bone.x_axis
    z2 = p_bone.z_axis

    # lets see the diferences..
    v_point = (v1 - v2).magnitude
    x_point = (x1 - x2).magnitude
    z_point = (z1 - z2).magnitude
    # lets get the total score
    total = v_point + x_point + z_point
    # with better score total sould be smaller,
    # but it returns zero at multiple angles
    # this only can happen if the scene does't update.
    print(angle, total)
    return (angle, total)
```

Comment: Could you please fix your indenting.  Can use blender text editor. Select all, hit tab, (tabs all one to the right, the formatting needed for bse)  copy .. paste here.  shift-tab tabs back.

Comment: oops, I fixed now.

Comment: Try `scene.update()`  I think `frame_set` does update, but maybe not for `scene.frame_current`

Comment: Still getting many zero scores, as if the values didn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Run this example on a sample start up file, with cube selected. What result to you expect to get.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
obj = context.object 

v1 = obj.location
# move the object 
obj.location += Vector((1, 1, 1))
#update the scene
scene.update()
# get the new location
v2 = obj.location
# print the result.
print(v1, v2, v2 - v1)
```

The result

```
<Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)> <Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)> <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
```

The context object clearly moves, but the vectors `v1` and `v2` both have the same value.  This is because `v1` is a reference to `obj.location` and not to the value when set.  To get the value when set:

[**Use `Vector.copy()`**](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.copy)

> "*use this to get a copy of a wrapped vector with no reference to the
>   original data*"

Use [`Vector.copy()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.copy) whenever you want to get a snapshot of a `Vector` value. Otherwise `v1 = p_bone.vector` will always equal `v2 = p_bone.vector` as it is a reference to the value, `p_bone.vector`.
This is one (major) reason you are always getting 0s.

Also worth noting: blender natively uses radians as a measure of angle. 180 as radians is `degrees(180)` or 10313.24 degrees, which is rather nonsensical.

Comment: Even, the same pattern of zeros.
Look: https://postimg.org/image/dzyimsgk5/

Comment: Oh well that's that then.   Simply wiriting no it still doesn't work is somewhat annoying, given that code as was with reference to vector would give zero on for each of `(v2 - v1) , (x2 - x1), (z2 - z1)`.  Ever thought about  posting a link to changed code,  ,  and a sample file to run it on.  You do know that blender uses radians natively for angles?   You could  add  descriptive print statements to make it easier to debug.