# What do I need to become a Blender developer?

Tags: development

I have been wanting to become a developer for some time. I want to keep software up to date and put some ideas in practice, like creating a remesher with flow detection.
I like to use python to write my software.

The point is, I am not a very good programmer (actually, scripter), but I'm sure that some I can write some cool tools no one will write for me.

- So if I want to be a developer, where do I start?
- What are the requrements for that?
- What do I need to learn?
- Can anyone be a developer?

Comment: I'm not a developer but you should start small, if you know a little bit of Python create some useful addons. Maybe these books will help https://www.blendermarket.com/creators/varkenvarken Then once you get a better idea about what it takes to code in Blender you can make more complicated add-ons. Then you can learn C++ and really get deep into Blender coding. It takes years of learning and practice. Just keep at it.

Comment: IMO this q is bordering on off topic: _primarily opinion based_  On your path to becoming a dev, I'd like you to revisit this [q & a](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89906/context-frame-set-not-updating-every-time)  Having a small project to work on will get you well on your way, and code demonstrates that you've had a red hot go before asking a question.    _note  the comments below  my answer_     (little gruff and sarcastic, I'm bad) It's all about giving you a nudge... rather than writing  code for you, where you learn nothing.

Comment: Yes, I actually have a small project, but I take as finished by fault of reference, I just leave without that operator, since nothing I tried worked. Actually I am using the finished addon right now. There's just a bug I need to fix before share.

Comment: @batFINGER and as you can see, I am really not a good programmer, but still I want to learn as fast I can.
You can take a look on my earlier finished little projects. https://github.com/jeacom25b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question! There are many ways to help developing Blender. The best way is to find things to improve first, like fixing bugs. That'll help getting familiar with the code and structure of Blender. The first place to start is the wiki page https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Contents, mostly the "Getting Started" section.

Also drop by on IRC, channel #blendercoders on Freenode. There you'll find friendly developers you can ask all kind of questions.

Answer (score 3):

You say you have done some python scripting so you have already started. Look around here, can you provide an answer to any questions that have a python tag? Can you solve other answers with a script? Search blender's [api reference](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/contents.html) to help make your answer. Read other python answers to learn something new. Stuck with something? ask a question and learn from the answer.

The only requirement is a desire to help and some ability to solve problems, even if you don't know how, start searching and experimenting to find the answer. The more you do the more you will know and the quicker you will get at providing solutions.

As you know blender uses python for it's addons, have an idea? [make an addon](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html) and share it. If it is good enough you may be able to get it included with blender releases. Find other addon projects and see if you can fix any of the bug reports or make improvements, then submit patches to be included. You can find some by searching gihub for [blender addon](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=blender%20addon&type=).

Want to help the official blender development? Search blender's [bug tracker](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/) for addon, UI or python bug reports, note that not all UI and python bugs will be fixed with python, some may need the underlying C/C++ code fixed. If you can fix one then submit a patch to be included. Think an addon can be improved? make the change and submit a patch.

Yes anyone can be a developer, how well you do and how much you contribute to other projects is up to you.